# Azure AD SSO for argocd cli

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory, argocd

I'm trying to script some of our argocd tasks - i.e add repos, but I'm unable to get SSO work via cli, it works just fine via the Web UI. I added http://localhost:8085/auth/callback as a Redirect URIs for my app registration however i'm getting an error when running the following command:

```
$ argocd login argocd.foobar.local --sso --grpc-web                                                      
Opening browser for authentication
INFO[0002] RequestedClaims: map[groups:essential:true ]
Performing authorization_code flow login: https://login.microsoftonline.com/*************/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?access_type=offline&claims=%7B%22id_token%22%3A%7B%22groups%22%3A%7B%22essential%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D&client_id=**************&code_challenge=**************&code_challenge_method=S256&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8085%2Fauth%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email+offline_access&state=rPJPPwlfYj
```

```
FATA[0004] oauth2: cannot fetch token: 401 Unauthorized
Response: {"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"AADSTS7000218: The request body must contain the following parameter: 'client_assertion' or 'client_secret'.\r\nTrace ID: cb7f1c22-d02b-4229-b382-264e01b00200\r\nCorrelation ID: 8db27be0-ea53-447d-b268-0d5549322fb4\r\nTimestamp: 2022-02-10 23:30:33Z","error_codes":[7000218],"timestamp":"2022-02-10 23:30:33Z","trace_id":"cb7f1c22-d02b-4229-b382-264e01b00200","correlation_id":"8db27be0-ea53-447d-b268-0d5549322fb4","error_uri":"https://login.microsoftonline.com/error?code=7000218","claims":"{\"access_token\":{\"capolids\":{\"essential\":true,\"values\":[\"***********\"]}}}"}
```

Is there something on the Azure Side i need to configure to allow for this? Or do i need to pass more arguments to my argocd cli?